# A multivariable non-linear recurrence relation

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

The question comes from an [interview problem](https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Interview/You-have-r-red-balls-w-white-balls-in-a-bag-If-you-keep-drawing-balls-out-of-the-bag-until-the-bag-now-only-contains-ball-QTN_2924430.htm) that reads as follows:

> There is a bag with $w$ white balls and $r$ red balls. You iteratively
>   extract one ball per time from the bag until only one is left. What is
>   the probability that the last ball is red?

How to solve the problem above?

My approach is to write down a recurrence relation:
$$p(w,r) := \mathbb{P}(\text{last ball is red }| \;w \text{  white balls and } r \text{ red balls} ),$$
then
$$p(r,w) = \frac{r}{r+w}\,p(r-1, w) + \frac{w}{r+w}\,p(r, w-1)$$
with initial conditions
$$p(r,0) = 1, \qquad p(0,w) = 0.$$

Looking at a few examples one comes up with and verifies that
$$p(r,1) = \frac{r}{r+1}.$$

To solve the general case I considered the generating function
$$G(x,y) := \sum_r \sum_w p(r,w) x^r y^w,$$
but, since the recurrence relation is non-linear, it is not obvious to me how to find a functional equation for it.

On a side note: In the link it is claimed that the solution is $p(r,w) = \frac{r}{r+w}$; but this does not satisfy the recurrence relation and seems to be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure $p(r,w)=\frac{r}{r+w}$ does not satisfy the recurrence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the balls are distinct (numbered) and we order them according to the extraction order.

Then the number of total arrangements are $(w+r)!$ and the successfull ones are $ r  (r+w-1)!$

Because all arrangements are equiprobable the probability of success is then

$$ \frac{r  (r+w-1)!}{(w+r)!}=\frac{r}{w+r}$$

More simply: by symmetry, the probability of the last ball being red is the same of the first ball being red. Which is $\frac{r}{w+r}$

Your recursion is ok, and the solution above satisfies it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little embarassed for my wrong computation...